# tokenize math expressions

Tags: python, tokenize

I am working a Shunting Yard program in Python and running into a problem with a math expression such as "3x + 4 * y" or "3 sin(x)".

The problem is that the Python tokenize function doesn't know that I need "3x" to become ["3", "*" "x"] instead of just ["3", "x"].  I can, of course, stipulate that the user must enter 3*x instead of just 3x but that's so lame.  There should be a cleaner way to get around this.

Here's the tokenizing code I am using (copied from stackoverflow postings):

```
expression="3x + 4*y"
from io import StringIO
print [token[1] for token in tokenize.generate_tokens (StringIO(expression).readline) if token[1]]
```

which gives me:

```
[u'3', u'x', u'+', u'4', u'*', u'y']
```

but I need:

```
[u'3', u'*', u'x', u'+', u'4', u'*', u'y']
```

in order for the Shunting Yard code to work properly.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Sorry for the typo.  What I need should be:

Comment: [sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/manipulation.html) might offer what you need... and maybe not. sorry; `3x` also won't work there.

Comment: That tokenizer tokenizes python code, not mathematical expressions with some non-pythony syntax.

Comment: What else did you expect? `tokenize` is a "lexical scanner for Python source code." It tokenizes according to Python syntax, which of course, does not infer the `*` operator... So it looks like you need to implement your own tokenizer.

Comment: Also, there really is no token for "*" there. This sort of thing should happen during parsing, which you need anyway to evaluate the expression.

Comment: @Neme good point.

Comment: May be I am doing it in the wrong place.  May be I should handle that in the Shunting Yard code...

Comment: Thanks, everybody.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pay attention to the types of the tokens returned and preprocess the token array to get what you want. In your example, 3x results in a NUMBER followed by a NAME token. Insert the implied OP token and you're away.